# Suggested Edit queue shows conflict warning for my own edit after submitting improvement

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, improve-edit, concurrency

*After* reviewing https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42519 as <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> and submitting the improvement, I got the orange header bar telling me the post had been edited twice and I should reload, yadda yadda. But, looking at the [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/254578/revisions), it's clear that that simply isn't the case; the only two revisions are the one I was reviewing and the one I made myself.

So the warning needs to avoid that particular race condition.